# Column history - save

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

small beginner here. 
I need to do copy values from one column and paste them in another one. 
Firstly, i try something like "saveHistoryColumn". It works, but I do not wanna write variables from A-ZZ......Therefore I was looking for some looping, "Test" worsk, but my question is how to place the original data from B--> A, D-->C etc. in one sheet ? The test copy value from sheet 1 to sheet at same position...

```
function saveHistoryColumn() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!B15:B20");
var source2 = ss1.getRange ("Sheet1!D15:D20");

source.copyTo (ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A15:A20"), {contentsOnly: true});
source2.copyTo (ss1.getRange ("Sheet1!C15:C20"), {contentsOnly: true});
}  



function test () {try {
var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var rlist = sheet.getRangeList(["B1:B10","D1:D10"]);

sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // target will be Sheet1 A1:A10,C1:C10... etc.
for( var i=0; i<rlist.getRanges().length; i++ ) {
  var r1 = rlist.getRanges()[i];
  var r2 = sheet.getRange(r1.getA1Notation());
  r1.copyTo(r2);

}}  catch(err) {
Logger.log(err);}}
```

Comment: Can you explain this better? "but my question is how to place the original data from B--> A, D-->C etc."

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
function backupColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  for(col = 1; col < sheet.getLastColumn(); col+=2) {
    var values = sheet.getRange(1, col + 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    sheet.getRange(1, col, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

to copy each even column into each odd if that's what you want